# How can I derive the waiting time distribution of gaussian processes?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-mechanics

Given two successive Gaussian events,

$X_1 \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2),\qquad X_2\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\qquad$ with $X_2 = X_1+\epsilon$,$\quad\epsilon\in {\rm I\!R},\quad\epsilon>0$

how can I derive the distribution function of the waiting time, $\epsilon$, between them?

$X_2 - X_1 = \epsilon \sim ~?$

In other words, if the time at which a certain event is detected follows a Gaussian distribution, what is, or how can I derive, the distribution of the time interval between two successive events?

---

**[Edit]**

My original question was much less detailed than I originally thought, so I will try to give a better example.

Suppose I have a time series with random peaks. If I look at the distribution of those peaks in time I will see a [Gaussian distribution of times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZLvj.png).

Now I want to look at the distribution of the time interval between peaks (or waiting time). I get this [distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV82E.png) that looks like an exponential distribution. But I know it isn't a true exponential distribution. I want to know which distribution it is or how to derive it.

Comment: Do they share the same mean $\mu$ or are the means and variances different?

Comment: More importantly, what assumptions are you placing on the relationship between $X_2-X_1$ and $X_1$?

Comment: A waiting time is a meaningful concept in a Poisson process, but less so with a Gaussian process where the difference can be negative

Comment: They do share the same mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. About $X_1$ and $X_2$: they are both time values at which a certain event is detected. I know that the distribution of those time values is Gaussian but I want to look at the distribution of the waiting time between two detections.

Comment: Unfortunately, your addition doesn't really clarify things.  You've shown us only summary statistics for the $X_i$ individually.  What we need is information about the dependence between the $X_i$.

Comment: @norfair, you must think of them as ordered values (as they come from detections in the same time series). The next detection can't happen in the past, so $X_i<X_{i+1}$. I want to look at the distribution of $X_{i+1}-X_i=\epsilon>0$.